# DVD9 to DVD-R Conversion

Tags: dvd, video-conversion

is it possible to strip out multiligual audio from DVD9 (7.95 GB) and keep English Audio 2.0 without touching the video quality and have it burn on a DVD-R (4.7 GB) Disc?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is very unlikely that removing the extra audio tracks will be enough to drop the size enough to fit on a single-layer DVD-R.  Generally, the audio tracks are 400MB or less, so unless you have four or more 5.1 tracks, you will have to re-encode the video at a lower quality.

However, if the DVD has numerous special features that you are willing to strip out, you can easily shave of a few GB of data.

I recommend using DVD Shrink 3.2. If you want just the movie by itself, go to the re-author tab, then drag the item under "Main Movie" to the left side. Then click the "Compression settings" tab and uncheck all the audio and subtitles you do not want.  This will minimize the quality loss from re-encoding by allowing it to encode at a higher quality, or if you remove enough special features and audio tracks, it may not need to reduce the video quality at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to strip out alternate language tracks with simple re-authoring, but 'without touching the video quality' depends entirely on the length and original bitrate. *Sometimes* it's possible, but sometimes even with stripping out all of the extras you aren't going to fit it on a single-layer disc without compressing it further. If you're using a Windows machine, you can download [DVDShrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/) for free.